# How use action-xhr and admin-post to send AMP form email

Tags: php, wordpress, amp-html

I have a website in wordpress and I am doing some pages in AMP, but I need to make a compatible form with AMP, [here](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/) I have the documentation, I'm having some difficulties mainly to connect the "action-xhr" with wordpress. I tried to make an eternal file but I had origin-across error.
[image]

```
<form target="_top" action-xhr="https://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="post" name="test">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="Name">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code, if you face any issue in integrating this, please let me know..

```
   <?php
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        /*/ this is the email we get from visitors*/
        $domain_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";

        /*//-->MUST BE 'https://';*/
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.ampproject.org");
        header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: ".$domain_url);


        /*/ For Sending Error Use this code /*/
        if(!mail("email@example.com" , "Test submission" , "email: $name <br/> name: $name" , "From: $name\n ")){
            header("HTTP/1.0 412 Precondition Failed", true, 412);

            echo json_encode(array('errmsg'=>'There is some error while sending email!'));
            die();
        }
        else
        {
            /*/--Assuming all validations are good here--*/
            header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");   

                echo json_encode(array('successmsg'=>$_POST['name'].'My success message. [It will be displayed shortly(!) if with redirect]'));
            die();
        }
    }?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, the code apparently works because when I click on send it appears the classes "user-valid amp-form-submit-success" but nothing arrives in my email. Could something be missing?
Thanks

Comment: I am using the wordpress AMP plugin, everything seems fine I used your code for php and I changed the part of putting the email and I loaded it in the main folder of my site wp.
I changed this part for my email: `!mail("myemail@gmail.com"`
my form is 
`<form target="_top" action-xhr="https://mywebsite.com/email-amp.php" method="post" name="test">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="name">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>`
Does not carry any type of error in the console.

Comment: set target as "_blank" *;*  
did you receive mail successfully *;*  where these classes being used "user-valid amp-form-submit-success"